# How can I compare multiple variables in C?

Tags: c, comparison-operators

How can I compare multiple variables to see if they all are the same? (e.g a==b==c) I know that you can do 
    if (a==b) && (a==c) && (b==c) {}
but with many variables (in my case 9) that's not a good way to do it.

EDIT: I don't need every variable compared to each other (the && (b==c) part). I wanted to compare all the values to see if they are the same so comparing (a==b) && (a==c) && (a==d) etc is the same thing. I just don't want to repeat code (like the (a==b) && (a==c) && (a==d) example).

Comment: This looks much like an exact repost of a question some hours ago. If that was closed, sou should have edited it and asked to re-open instead of deleting it and reposting. Anyway, it is still not clear what your actual problem is. See what the operators yield and think again.

Comment: Put them in array and loop over.

Comment: Your third comparison `b==c` isn't even necessary.

Comment: Well, N-1 comparisons for N variables..

Comment: @olaf yeah the previous question was about another thing. I worked it out.

Comment: Hint `a == b && a == c && a == d...`, can you see the pattern here?

Comment: @JohnGRThess: I have quite a good memory and the question was much the same.

Comment: I feel nine isn't "many" ... - however "looping" is the generic solution to do similar/same stuff often in a "row".

Answer (score 4):

Note that you don't have to compare all of the variables to each other, you just have to compare each one to one other.  In other words, if you have N variables that you know are equal, then if the next one is equal to one of the N, it's equal to all of them.

So to compare N variables for equality you need N-1 comparisons, not 1 + 2 + ... + N - 1 = (N-1)(N-2)/2.

For example:

```
if (a==b && b==c && c==d && d==e && e==f && f==g && g==h && h==i) {
   ...
```

Since the `&&` operator is a short-circuit operator, the evaluation of the condition will stop once one of the subexpressions evaluates to false.

If all of these values were part of an array, you could do it with a loop:

```
int equal = 1;
for (i=0;(i<len-1) && equal;i++) {
    equal = equal && (a[i] == a[i+1]);
}
```

The additional `&& equal` in the `for` condition will break out of the loop early if `equal` ever evaluates to false.

Comment: So that's 8 comparisons, not the 45 required by OP's thought, which of course would be unwieldy.

Comment: An early break on unequal comparison might be a good idea if there are more than few values (the threshold depends on the architecture).

Comment: Just another note: With `bool equal`, you could use `equal &= (a[ ...` (the short circuit evaluation is not required here). (the latter is more a matter of taste).

Comment: `equal = equal && (a[i] == a[i+1]);` can be simplified to `equal = (a[i] == a[i+1]);`, because the loop condition ensures that at this point `equal` is true, and `1 && something` can be simplified to `something`.

Answer (score 2):

Stringing equality operators like that can lead to "unexpected" results:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
        int a = 1, b = 2, c = 0;
        printf("%d\n", a == b == c);
        return 0;
}
```

This prints `1` ("true"), even though all numbers are different. That's because `a == b` is `0` ("false"), and comparing that to `c = 0` yields `1` ("true").

A solution to your question would be something like:

```
int all_equal(int *a, int size)
{
        int i;
        for(i=1; i<size; i++)
                if(a[0] != a[i])
                        return 0;
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, but it doesn't answer the question: how can he check that 9 variables are equal? It seems the OP thinks it is necessary to compare every variable with every other. If you add the proper way of doing it, your answer will be perfect.

Comment: I wanted to show first what the problem of his expression is, and that C code does not necessarily behave like math.

Comment: @FabioTurati I don't need to compare every variable with every other. Also I don't want to do a==b && a==c && a==d etc I just want to do a==b==c==d which doesn't work

Comment: @JohnGRThess Well, but in your question you *are* comparing every variable to every other. You are comparing `if (a==b) && (a==c) && (b==c)`. You only need any 2 of those 3 blocks, not all 3. That's what everybody is saying in comments and answers, and rightfully so.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa: It is well possible OP knows this from Python.

Answer (score 1):

not claiming efficiency here, but if you have that many (although 9 isn't that many) or more, putting them in an array and looping through it should do it. Just using `bool`s as the type here:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_INTS 9

int myInts[NUM_INTS];
// initialize myInts

int i;
bool allEqual = true;

for (i = 1; i < NUM_INTS; i++)
{
   if (myInts[0] != myInts[i])
   {
      allEqual = false;
      break;
   }
}

// allEqual == true if all are equal, false otherwise
```

This doesn't do *every* comparison, but it should do enough to know. As pointed out in the comments, if `a==b` and `a==c` then we know `b==c` without having to check.

Comment: Note: `stdbool.h` is required to get the `bool` etc. macros.

Comment: While I appreciate your code using `bool`, problem is your code compares booleans, but I think OP wants to compare other numeric types, e.g. `int` or `float`.

Comment: @Olaf Did I miss that somewhere in the OP? Looks like he just specified "variables". Nevertheless... I have no reason to use `bool`s, that was just the first type that came to mind. I think dbush has the better answer anyway, although since `bool`s were introduced into `C` I prefer using them for true/false rather than `int`s.

Comment: It is better padded with text. But I like the eraly break approach. Just the array is a bad choice, because you could spare the comparison for a `bool` input (think about it;-).